# HTML Javascript webpage content reading into a var

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say I have this weblink: http://checkip.amazonaws.com/ . I've made a java program (actual program. not webpage) that reads the content of this webpage (eg. "25.25.25.25") and displays it in a `jLabel` (Using Netbeans IDE 1.7.3) and it works.

Now how can I read the contents of this same webpage (eg. "25.25.25.25") and display it as normal text on a webpage (The final webpage must be .html not .php or what ever)?

I dont mind any script whether is html or javascript or anything, I just please need it to work so that when the webpage is opened it can read something like:

*"Your IP: 25.25.25.25"*

Preferably reading the contents of http://checkip.amazonaws.com/ into

```
<script>var ip = needCodeHere</script>
```

If I can get the IP into a var or read the contents of that webpage into a var I'm happy but other code is happy to as long as it works.

Please help :( been staring at google for days and cant find a solution)

Answer (score 5):

You'll need 3 files (in the same directory) to do that. A HTML file to show the ip, a PHP file to get that ip via curl, and a JS file to connect the html and the php. It would be simpler if the "final webpage" could be the ip.php itself, but let's do it this way:

1) ip.html (the "final webpage")

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ip.js"></script>

<div id="ip"></div>
```

2) ip.php

```
<?php
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://checkip.amazonaws.com');
  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
?>
```

3) ip.js

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ip.php',
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
      $('#ip').html("Your IP: " + data);
    }
  });
```

Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: More please :P ive only learn java scripting in school, webdesign is only next year and my teacher is being stingy :(. Thanx for the help :)

Comment: I made the 3 files. hosted them on internet, changed directories to the files directories on the internet e.t.c how it all should be but i cant gt it working :(

Comment: Basicly i want my webpage to look something like: Welcome!. Your IP: [need ip here] has been captured, Please dont steal e.t.c (so i just need it to scare them :P)

Comment: Also cause my webpage www.tera--byte.tk will mainly turn into a gaming website and you know how freaked out gamers get when they think they will get ddosed even though i dont know how to :P. i just hope they will fall for it and dont steal my stuff

Comment: Well if you put all 3 files in the same directory, and open tera--byte.tk/ip.html, you'll get what you need. 
Ofc you have to configure your webserver (apache?) correctly to point your domain to the folder where the 3 files are, did you do that?

Comment: Thats the other problem. my website is hosted on dropbox and the .tk domain just redirects it to my dropbox url, each page has a different directory, its not just ./what ever. yes i changed the page directorys in the files to the correct ones and its not working

Comment: Thanx for the help guys but i can live without it. :) i dont really have a reason to scare people now since i got nothing i dont want them to have. all my stuff is free html css theme downloads i just edited and put on dropbox. not much to it, thanx for the replies though